# AG Grid - Add rows of data to Master Detail without using JSON file

Tags: ag-grid, master-detail

I wanted to know how to add rows of data to the master detail table but not using an external json file and just write the row records inline via the JS

Anyone have any idea on how to go about this

https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/master-detail/

```
var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    // group cell renderer needed for expand / collapse icons
    { field: 'name', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
    { field: 'account' },
    { field: 'calls' },
    { field: 'minutes', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 'm'" },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  masterDetail: true,
  detailCellRendererParams: {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'callId' },
        { field: 'direction', minWidth: 150 },
        { field: 'number' },
        { field: 'duration', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'" },
        { field: 'switchCode', minWidth: 150 },
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
    getDetailRowData: function (params) {
      // simulate delayed supply of data to the detail pane
      setTimeout(function () {
        params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
      }, 1000);
    },
  },
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

// I dont want to use the external json file
  agGrid
    .simpleHttpRequest({
      url: 'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/master-detail-data.json',
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: of course you can add the data whatever way you like, not sure if I completely understand your question. Does [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/NWgzEzpu8mwKdsMW) Plunker help at all?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was after - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `rowData` field on the `gridOptions` like so:

```
var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    // group cell renderer needed for expand / collapse icons
    { field: 'name', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
    { field: 'account' },
    { field: 'calls' },
    { field: 'minutes', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 'm'" },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  masterDetail: true,
  detailCellRendererParams: {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'callId' },
        { field: 'direction' },
        { field: 'number', minWidth: 150 },
        { field: 'duration', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'" },
        { field: 'switchCode', minWidth: 150 },
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
    getDetailRowData: function (params) {
      params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
    },
  },
  onFirstDataRendered: onFirstDataRendered,
  rowData: myData
};
```

In this instance, `myData` would look like this:

```
var myData = [
  {
    name: 'Nora Thomas',
    account: 177000,
    calls: 24,
    minutes: 25.65,
    callRecords: [
      {
        name: 'susan',
        callId: 555,
        duration: 72,
        switchCode: 'SW3',
        direction: 'Out',
        number: '(00) 88542069',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/NWgzEzpu8mwKdsMW?preview).